# Should using Eval carry the same stigma as GoTo?

Tags: eval, goto

It is taught in every computer science class and written in many books that programmers should not use GoTo. There is even an [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/292/) comic about it. My question is have we reached a point where the same thing can be said about Eval?

Where GoTo is not conductive for program flow and readability,
Eval is the same for debugging, and program execution, and design.

Should using Eval have the same stigma as GoTo, and same consequences as in the xkcd comic?

Comment: Well, I certainly don't expect it to have the same consequences as in the comic... I'd have been eaten a few times by now.

Comment: This is a tangent, but the goto controversy is a farce. Goto is only bad when people use it stupidly. Same with eval. Eval is very powerful, flexible, and dangerous in the wrong hands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If anything, it should carry more stigma.

GoTo often creates code that's difficult to maintain. Eval often creates code with security vulnerabilities - that's worse.

Answer (score 2):

Eval has some fairly serious security concerns; if there's any chance untrusted or user-supplied input can end up in an eval, it's vulnerable.

Jslint will warn about usage of eval() in js code run through it.

Answer (score 1):

May be eval hasn't reached the levels of criticism that GoTo reached, but certainly its deprecated!

Answer (score 1):

It's only a matter of time before someone publishes a "Eval considered Evil" article!

Comment: followed by the "'Eval considered Evil' considered Evil" article.

Answer (score 0):

"Exploits of a Mom" indirectly covers eval - malicious code is run by the system due to lack of proper checking.